# Como instanciar uma classe com parametros pré-definidos e imutáveis C#

Tags: c#, lista, classes, enums

Como instanciar essa classe `jogo`?

```cs
public class Jogo
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; }
        public string Plataform { get; }

        public Jogo(string name, string genre, string plataform)
        {
            Name = name;
            Genre = genre;
            Plataform = plataform;
        }
}
```

com os parametros 'genre' e 'plataform' de uma lista pre-definida e imutável?

Pensei em `enum`:

```cs
enum Genre { Ação, Plataforma, FPS, Aventura, Corrida };

// ou uma lista
var plataform = new List<string>(){ "PS4", "PS5", "Xbox One", "Xbox Series X" };
```

Mas não consegui instanciar

```cs
var game = new Jogo("God  of War", <item da List ou Enum>, <item da List ou Enum>);


// eu tentei mudar a propriedade na class 'Jogo'
// com List:
        public List<string> Genre { get; }
        public List<string> Plataform { get; }
// ou com enum
        public Genre category{ get; }
        public System Plataform { get; }
```

**Como instanciar?**

Com uma classe para 'Plataform' e outra para 'Genre'... ou um enum dentro de 'Jogo'? Qual a melhor implementação?

Comment: Não entendi? ...

Comment: Eu tenho a class Jogo, na hora de instanciar eu queria limitar as opções do segundo parametro 'genre', para não colocar qualquer coisa. Ou seja: new Jogo("string_qualquer", Genre.Ação, Plataform.PS4); Assim eu evito erros do tipo  new Jogo("string_qualquer", "banana", "pessego");

Comment: Então não use strings para o tipo do campo, se o que quer é uma classe ou um enum. C# permite definir o tipo do campo. Use como linguagem de tipagem estática, não dinâmica.

Comment: tenteu `enum`?.

Comment: estou tentando de novo. Caramba deu!

Comment: vou colocar a solução, caso alguém tenha a mesma duvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tem uma lista definida e imutável utilize `enum`, ***exemplo***:

```
public enum Genres
{    
    Acao, 
    Plataforma, 
    FPS, 
    Aventura, 
    Corrida
}

public enum Plataforms
{
    PS4, 
    PS5, 
    XboxOne, 
    XboxSeriesX
}
```

e por fim:

```
public class Jogo
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Genres Genre { get; }
        public Plataforms Plataform { get; }

        public Jogo(string name, Genres genre, Plataforms plataform)
        {
            Name = name;
            Genre = genre;
            Plataform = plataform;
        }
}
```

e na sua instância:

```
var jogo = new Jogo("Jogo 1", Genres.Acao, Plataforms.PS4);
```

Answer (score 0):

resolvi assim:
criando uma classe `Jogo`

```cs
public class Jogo
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Genre Category { get; }
        public string Plataform { get; set; }

        public Jogo(string name, Genre category, string plataform)
        {
            Name = name;
            Category = category;
            Plataform = plataform;
        }
    }
```

Criei um enum `Genre.cs`

```cs
{
    public enum Genre
    {
        Ação, Aventura, Corrida, Luta
    }
}
```

e instanciei assim no `program > main`

```cs
      var game = new Jogo("gow", Genre.Ação, "PS4");
      Console.WriteLine(game.Category);
     //# Ação
```